# How to get glow on the buttons like ipod/ipad in Android

Tags: android

On Android application How can I get the glow effect on button when touched; I am looking for exact similar effect like ipod/iphone buttons

Comment: Agreed, you have 9 questions, none of them has an accepted answer - we're not going to waste our time for that

Comment: Most of the answers to all the questions were not 100% a solution; but I have now accepted 2 answers which provided me the right directions. I am going through more questions and checking if i can accept more answers If appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html). Type this into a file and store it as **res/drawable/button_bg.xml**. Then create 4 images `button_press.png`, `button_focus.png`, `button_disabled.png` and `button.png` and last set your background to `button_bg`. If you want your button glow when touch you can add an image of your glowing button to state `press`. So when you press the system will get `glowing_button.png` and display it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_press" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focus" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
</selector>
```

The "magic" behind this is that android will go from the top to bottom and use the first one matching your buttons state.

Answer (score 0):

In these links you can find some snippets to get exactly the same TabBar as iOS applications

- [iPhone Tab in Android](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android)
- [TabHost For Android](https://github.com/honcheng/ScrollableTabHost-for-Android)
- [iTabs](http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/iphone-tabs-for-android-t14678.html)

Comment: I am looking for glow effect not tab

Comment: Did you open those links? There you have a TabBar with buttons with the glow effect you're looking for. All of these libraries/snippets are open source so you can get only the lines of code you need (in your case, the ones that make the glow effect)

Comment: @Mangusto You should extract the code which help OP not give him to another research.